# Read user uploaded csv file and store data in Django modele live on heroku

Tags: django, csv, heroku

This is my firts question here. so I would like to thank you for your help.

I have a Django School management app. and i would like the user to be able to read csv file and store in database with specific header.

My code runs locally very well. but I recently push it on heroku so that I can test it. I may note that all static assets are stored on Amazon s3. and it works.

but when I try to read a csv file, I get an Internal server error.

here is my code to store Pupils.

```
def convert_header(csvHeader):
    cols = [ x.replace(' ', '_').lower() for x in csvHeader ]
    return cols

def import_data(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'school/import.html')

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:

        if request.POST.get("object") == '':
            message = 'You may chose an object'
            return render(request, 'school/import.html', {'message': message })

        if request.POST.get("object") == 'Pupil':
            myfile = request.FILES['myfile'] 

            fs = FileSystemStorage(location='eSchool/media/documents')
            filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
            uploaded_file_url = fs.path(filename)

            data = csv.reader(open(uploaded_file_url), delimiter=',')

            header = next(data)
            header_cols = convert_header(header)
            i = 0
            k = 0
            for row in data:
                pupil = Pupil()
                for k in range(len(header_cols)):
                    row_item = row[k].split(',')
                    for item in row_item:
                        key = header_cols[k]
                        if key == 'responsible':
                            item = Responsible.objects.get(pk= int(item))
                            print(item.first_name)
                            setattr(pupil, key, item)
                        else:
                            setattr(pupil, key, item)   
                    k +=1

                pupil.save()
                i = i + 1
            detailed = 'Sucessfully created '+ str(i) + ' Pupils '
            return render(request,  'school/import_success.html', {'detailed' : detailed })
```

I would like to store data in a modele called Document. I create it. and try it I still get the error. Please help.

Comment: show your error message

Comment: When I run it locally, there no error. But when i go live, I get this error just in the browser: Internal server error

Comment: You can see the error log by doing `heroku logs`.

Comment: When I run heroku logs, i get this "2017-10-08T14:23:02.745819+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/home/import/data/" host=cemmah.herokuapp.com request_id=cd8d8053-f475-4309-8cdd-b400b7c66c16 fwd="190.115.178.103" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=332ms status=500 bytes=7895 protocol=https"

Comment: So the error status is 500. I think the problem is that Django does not deal with the static file on server same way as local. But now I need to find a way to read the file when i go live. Thank you so far for seeing my question and add comment.

Comment: I am trying to read a litle bit more about the Django FileSystemStorage class. So I am not realy an expert of Django. I am So Ithink you can find much more sense than me in the documentation: so link is : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/storage/

Comment: I solve the problem. I post the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution of that problem. I first create a Django model to store the url of the uploaded file. like that:

```html
class Document(models.Model):
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

Obvously I had to configure MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL
I configure the settings file to store the reference of all media assets and all static file on Amazon s3.

So instead of using the class FileSystemStorage. I install with pip a package named "requests"

pip install requests

and I import requests,csv and codecs.

```html
import requests
import codecs
```

After that my view I just make litle modification tm my function.

```html
def import_data(request):
 if request.method == 'GET':
  return render(request, 'school/import.html')

 if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:

  if request.POST.get("object") == '':
   message = 'You may chose an object'
   return render(request, 'school/import.html', {'message': message })

  if request.POST.get("object") == 'Pupil':
   myfile = request.FILES['myfile'] 
   doc = Document()
   doc.upload = myfile
   doc.save()
   print(doc.upload.url)
   if settings.DEBUG == True: # execute that block locally
    data = csv.reader(open(doc.upload.path), delimiter=',') # locally the file is red frm the path so i us doc.upload.path
   else: #this block is executed in production. So the file is red from the url. so I use doc.upload.url
    rep = requests.get(doc.upload.url)
    text = codecs.iterdecode(rep.iter_lines(), 'latin_1') #codecs is use to decode the lines. I don't really master how it works.
    data = csv.reader(text, delimiter = ',')
   header = next(data)
   header_cols = convert_header(header)
   i = 0
   k = 0
   for row in data:
    pupil = Pupil()
    for k in range(len(header_cols)):
     row_item = row[k].split(',')
     for item in row_item:
      key = header_cols[k]
      if key == 'responsible':
       item = Responsible.objects.get(pk= int(item))
       #print(item.first_name)
       setattr(pupil, key, item)
      else:
       setattr(pupil, key, item) 
     k +=1
    
    pupil.save()
    i = i + 1
   detailed = 'Sucessfully created '+ str(i) + ' Pupils '
   return render(request,  'school/import_success.html', {'detailed' : detailed })
```

So right now. everything work well. If you see something that i can improve about this code, I Already thank you for your help!